# Double Entry Bookkeeping Database Design - Views vs Derived Tables vs Python Processing

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm starting to learn a bit about databases, and I've been reading for while about what is the best way to design a database for a simple accounting system with double entry.

For those who are not familiar with accounting, I have a `General Journal`, and I need to extract a few reports out of it - basically a bunch of `SUM IFS` (`sum` this account `if` this date).

I currently have my `journal` table designed as a one-liner, but I found [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/double-entry-bookkeeping-database-design) and [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102373/140182) that got me thinking.

Some parts of the answer that I would like to understand a bit better:

> *"...design a data structure that can be the numerical repository for
>   multiple journals..."*

- What would be an example of a numerical repository for multiple
  journals?

> *"...In a modern RDBMS... ...the General
>   Ledger, and even the specialized subledgers, can become Indexed Views
>   on the Journal, completely eliminating the requirement to code a
>   Posting Process (the step where a Journal transaction is locked and
>   has its account totals transcribed to the various ledgers)..."*

- How exactly should I deal with the "Indexed Views" approach?
- Create an indexed view for each Income Statement/Balance Sheet account?
- Maybe materialize a Pivot Table with all the acounts of the Income
  Statement/Balance Sheet in the columns (don't think that would be
  reasonable since I have about 150 accounts total)?

My query to extract a stock account (one that accumulates over time, such as Balance Sheet accounts):

```
SELECT Y, M,(@total := @total + Flow) AS TotalValue
FROM (
        SELECT year(dateacc) AS Y, month(dateacc) AS M, 
            (
                SUM(IF(Credit='Account', valor, 0))-
                SUM(IF(Debit='Account', valor, 0))
            ) AS BS_Account
        FROM journal
        GROUP BY YEAR(dateacc), MONTH(dateacc)
    ) AS T,
(SELECT @total:=0) AS n;
```

My query to extract a flow account (such as Income Statement Accounts):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datecash, '%m-%y') as DATA, 
    (
        SUM(IF(credit='Account', value, 0))-
        SUM(IF(debit='Account', value, 0))
    )
AS Flow 
FROM journal_test
GROUP BY YEAR(datecash), MONTH(datecash)
```

In a nutshell:

1. What is the best way to design this?
2. View vs Materialized View vs. Derived Table
3. How to approach the general journal vs. subledgers dilema